# how to get list of files in the server using C# not using ASP.net

Tags: c#

Am downloading a setup file from server, name of the setup file varies for each version so  before downloading it i need to get the file name

Comment: Since you mentioned ASP.Net, I assume this is a web project and you need to find a file name in code behind? You need to make sure that the files have access to be read from IIS.

Comment: What do you mean by **not using asp.net**? Do you mean you want your setup/or a desktop program to get filenames from the server?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking here, but if you want to get a list of all the files on the server using something along the lines of:-

```
string[] files = 
Directory.GetFiles
  (@"c:\myfolder\", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

or using linq

```
var files = from f in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myfolder\")
    where f.Contains(".exe")
    select f;
```

Once you get all the files then you need to iterate through the results and work out which one you want to return.

We probably need more info...

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to:

```
void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/demos");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
 foreach(FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
 {
  Response.Write("<br><a href=" + fi.Name + ">" + fi.Name + "</a>");       
 }
}
```

DirectoryInfo:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

OR

[Retrieving a List of Files from an FTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730626/retrieving-a-list-of-files-from-an-ftp-server-in-c)