# Socket.Receive does not block until all data is received

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

Ai!

I'm trying to get a ftp file list and already got a small library which did that. Thing is that the Socket.Receive() function does not block until all data is received. When i set a breakpoint at that line it receives all data but if i don't do that there are only 38 bytes (should be around 380).

Here is the code:

```
While True
    Dim bytes As Integer = cSocket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None)
    mes += ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes)
    If bytes < buffer.Length Then
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

As i said: it works if the breakpoint is set in the line with the .Receive part. I could use a workaround that guarantees one extra loop but that seems to be very dirty. Any ideas?

//edit: so let me add some more information. I don't know how much data i will receive. The code is from a function that receives data from a ftp server. I thought i could stop when the message ends with CRLF but i can't do that because there is a CRLF between each file that is listed. Example:
file1.textCRLFfile2.txtCLRFfile3.txtCRLF

Sometimes when i call receive it only returns one file with a CRLF at the end even if there are more files to be listed. So this condition seems unstable to me.

Comment: Try putting a debug.writeline(cSocket.available) before the receive.

Comment: You could use some existing code instead of implementing it yourself.

This answer for instance (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743101/132250).

Comment: Where does it say that Socket.Receive is supposed to receive all the data in one call? You won't find that written anywhere. You have to keep calling it until you have what you want.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly do you mean with "all data" in this case? Until the socket is closed, there can always be more data. The network stack doesn't know or care that some data logically belongs together. It gets chopped up in IP packets of varying sizes (determined by [complex algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).

For you as a receiving party, this means you will get data as it is being received, in chunks. You need to keep calling `Receive` until you know you have all the data you need.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26f591ax.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will
>   read as much data as is available, ***up to*** the number of bytes specified
>   by the size parameter.

The reason why you see different behavior when setting a breakpoint, is because you are literally pausing your application while the sending party is sending data. The operating system will still receive the packets and buffer them, up to a point. The standard buffer size is 8192 bytes and can be changed with the [`ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx) property.

### Code

How does this translate in code? Assuming you actually know how much data you need to receive, the improved code would look something like this:

```
Dim bytesRemaining As Integer = Buffer.Length
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
While bytesRemaining > 0
    Dim bytes As Integer = cSocket.Receive(Buffer,
                                           bytesRemaining, SocketFlags.None)
    bytesRemaining -= bytes
    sb.Append(ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, bytes))
End While
mes = sb.ToString()
```

The condition in your loop is gone, because we don't want to exit if we don't receive a lot of bytes, we want to keep reading. `bytesRemaining` keeps a running count of how many bytes are still to be received.

Not relevant to your question, but I've replaced the `mes` string concatenation with a `StringBuilder`. Potentially you would be creating a lot of new strings, who all (except for the last) need to be garbage collected.

Comment: @dbasnett Yes, the `Available` property returns the amount of bytes currently in the buffer.

Comment: What i meant is that the only condition in the code directly returns true and that stops the loop. So the mes string only contains one directory name at all. When i'm pausing the execution with a breakpoint there are all directory names. How is that possible? Evertyime i run the code above i only receive the name of the first directory or file and nothing more.

//update: another solution i figured out was to set a very small buffer (32). It works fine then.

Comment: @rob2109: That small buffer trick is, at best, a hack. It will fail if there's any delay in the communication.

Comment: @rob2109 In order to read all file names, you should remove that condition. I've added a code sample, but it assumes you know how much data you want to receive.

Comment: @Thorarin Sorry that i 'reopen' this thread. I know what you mean but i don't know how much data i will receive. My code has the purpose to get a file listing from a ftp server. I did not dive too deep into the ftp specs so can anyone tell me how do i know what the ending condition is? Are there any special chars at the end of the message?